# How automaticly find the newest version in apt for programes/libs with ver number in name ie gir1.2-cheese-3.0

Tags: bash, shell-script

In bash say Turning "gir1.2-cheese-3.0" into something like "gir-cheese".

```
sudo apt install gir-cheese
```

For example for a install config script in the next deb/ubu version run

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-cheese-3.0
```

Then when it fails randomly go up in number on both the 1.2 and 3.0 until it get the right version maybe with something to handle something like gir1.2.5-cheese-3.0 or even gir1.2.0.5-cheese-3.0

Any help is appreciated, Maybe there's a better way to Do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt` supports globs:

```
sudo apt install 'gir*-cheese-*'
```

This can be adapted to other similar package names. You can make the pattern more specific, see `man apt-patterns` for details.